# Using Kentico for Video Contest and voting. Is it possible?

Tags: kentico

im new to kentico, I wish to know if Kentico able to be use to build as a Contest website which allow user to submit photo & video then allow user to vote on entry?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can build a contest website in Kentico Xperience.

Even if Kentico Xperience doesn't have the functionality you need out of the box, you can extend it with some custom development.

You might want to utilise [Custom Modules](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/creating-custom-modules) functionality to store submissions and voting scores, and then you might want to build [widgets](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets) to allow for submission and voting.